# Экспорт table в xls файл с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, раздобыл я на просторах интернета скрипт для экспорта, немного переделал под мое приложение, есть проблемка, в хроме файл сохраняется в виде "Без названия.xls", а в мазиле в виде рандомного набора символов "hRTCg39T.xls" можно ли как-то сделать так что-бы задать сохраняемому файлу имя какое то, например "CSXL + Дата и время с сервера.xls"
Пример скрипта прилагается

```
function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
    var j=0;
    tab = document.getElementById('tableList'); 

    for(j = 2 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
    {     
        tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
    }

    tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); 
    tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

    sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + '\uFEFF' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  
    return (sa);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function fnExcelReport() {
  var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
  var j = 0;
  tab = document.getElementById('tableList');

  for (j = 2; j < tab.rows.length; j++) {
    tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
  }

  tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, "");
  tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,';
  var a = document.createElement('a');;
  a.setAttribute("href", uri + encodeURIComponent(tab_text))
  a.setAttribute('download', new Date() + '.xls');
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click()
}
fnExcelReport()
```

```html
<table id="tableList">
  <tr>
    <td>fff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, и такой вопрос, в эту часть `a.setAttribute('download', "любое имя" + '.xls');` можно через + вставить определение даты и времени с компьютера?

Comment: @СергейНиконенко конечно... добавил..)

Comment: так еще пару штуковин нужно узнать, вот тут  `a.setAttribute("href", uri +  encodeURIComponent(tab_text))` советую добавить `'\uFEFF' +`, так как если в таблице русские символы, почему-то выдает краказябры, а второе дата выводится в виде `Fri Dec 08 2017 11-08-36 GMT+0200 (Финляндия (зима))`, можно ли как-то сделать в виде `08.12.2017_11:11:23` - типа день.месяц.год_час.минута.секунда, а остальное не выводило?

Comment: @СергейНиконенко https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp этого хватин, чтобы распарсить дату..

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать, скрипты только сейчас начинаю учить)

Comment: @СергейНиконенко удачи..)

Comment: блин, почему-то не получается, сделал так `a.setAttribute('download', "CSXL01010_" + d.getDay() + "." + 
                                              d.getMonth() + "." + 
                                              d.getFullYear() + "_" + 
                                              d.getHours() + "." + 
                                              d.getMinutes() + "." + 
                                              d.getSeconds() + '.xls');`, но почему то день берет 5, хотя сегодня 8

Comment: тут понял поменял `getDay()` на `getDate()`, а вот что с месяцем делать, не пойму, берет максимум 11 как я понял(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69893/discussion-between---and-c-raf-t).

Comment: от 0 до 11... как любой массив..)

Answer (score 1):

getDay() это день недели..... и не желательно точки

Comment: ну точки по постановке задачи поставили, а почему нельзя?